# Pycharm: Why is the file name of my html shown in green when all the other file names are white?

Tags: python, pycharm

Here is what I am talking about :
[image]

Can someone explain? I've been using Pycharm for more than 2 months now and that's the first time I see that. I can't find an answer to it, but it seems to happen whenever I comment out some code (so weird).

Comment: I don't use PyCharm, but is it new and untracked in version control? Or tracked but modified? Or modified but not saved?

Comment: I'm not sure if you've modified the default theme, but see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/file-status-highlights.html Looks like maybe it's been renamed?

Comment: As @Chris points out: PyCharm does that for modified files or for new files that have been added to Git (staged for commit) but not committed yet. If uses red if the file is new but not staged for commit. And it tends to stage new files unless otherwise told, so it bet is that. So: If `base.html` is under version control and you made a change, it'll show green to show uncommited changes.

Comment: oooh ok. Yeah I get it now it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Chris and BorrajaX, I understand that this happens when you modify a file project that is on a git repo but didnt commit yet the change.
Thanks a lot